# What is the range of a VHDL integer definition VHDL-2019?

Tags: vhdl

While using the VHDL-2019  IEEE spec
section. 5.2.3.1. General

> "However, an implementation shall allow the declaration of any integer
>   type whose range is wholly contained within the bounds –(2**63) and
>   (2**63)–1 inclusive."

(I added the exponential **)

Does this mean  –(2**63) = -9223372036854775808 ?

In the 1993 spec it states  -((2**31) - 1)  and (2**31) - 1)
-2147483647 & 2147483647

Does the new VHDL spec have an error in that definition?

Ken

Comment: So, Should I put in a bug report against the doc?  If so,  how?  -- Ken

Comment: The first comment is an opinion without supporting basis.

Comment: I think the older standards had the odity, as a case where you had a 32 bit (C) integer with the hex value 0x80000000 (-2147483648) would not be covered by VHDL's integer range.

Comment: Prior to 2019, the range allowed the underlying computer to support either 2's complement or 1's complement arithmetic.   AFAIK, there is not a 1's complement arithmetic computer on which a simulator currently runs.  Hence, no need to continue allowing for 1's complement machines.   if the implementation supports only 2's complement arithmetic, then maybe one day we will be able to do more with type integer - such as implement "and" operators since A and 16#FFFF# would then always return the same result.

Answer (score 6):

The change is quite intentional. See [LCS2016_026c](http://www.eda-twiki.org/cgi-bin/view.cgi/P1076/LCS2016_026c).  You could note this gives the same range as a 64 bit integer in programming languages. The non-symmetrical effect comes from two's complement numbers which are the basis of integer types in VHDL tool implementations, the age of big iron with decimal based ALUs long faded.

The previous symmetrical range was not an implementation concern, VHDL arithmetic semantics requires run time detection of rollover or underflow. This change allows simpler detection based on changing signs without testing values while performing arithmetic in yet a larger than 64 bits *universal integer*.

The value range increase is an attempt to force synthesis vendors to support more than the minimum range specified in previous editions of the the standard. How well that works out (and over what implementation interval) will be a matter of history at some future date. There are also secondary effects based on index ranges (IEEE Std 1076-2019 5.3.2.2 Index constraints and discrete ranges) and positional correspondence for enumerated types (5.2.2 Enumerated types, 5.2.2.1 General). It's not practicable to simulate (or synthesize) composite objects with extreme index value ranges, starting with stack size issues. Industry practice isn't settled, and likely may result in today's HDLs being obsoleted.

Concerns to the accuracy of the standard's semantic description can be addressed to the IEEE-SAs VASG subcommittee which encourages participation by interested parties. You will find Stackoverflow [vhdl](/questions/tagged/vhdl) tag denizens here who have been involved in the standardization process.